# Buttons calling custom methods for Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm looking to add buttons to call my own methods instead of the CRUD methods (send to print, or download a PDF, or send an email, etc.) I see that I can create a button using addButtonFromModelFunction is this the only way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a button from Model function like below:

```
CRUD::addButtonFromModelFunction('top', 'export', 'getExportButtonHtml', 'beginning');
```

and the function `getExportButtonHtml` will look like:

```
public function getExportButtonHtml(): string
    {
        $queryString = request()->getQueryString();
        $params = $queryString ?? '';
        $route =  backpack_url('chart/export?'.$params);
        return "<a href='".$route."' class='btn btn-default btn-dark rounded bg-primary border-0'>
                <i class='la la-file-export'></i>
                <span>Export</span>
              </a>";
    }
```

Give it a try!!!

Comment: Thanks, I think I can figure out that way